# How can I use the DOM to change the href color of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to change a tab (Mathematic-tab)to a different href color (so I can't put .style.color = gold), when the value of 'aria-selected' from bootstrap becomes true. I currently have tabs of which mathematics tab is one and essentially I want to distinguish between a selected and unselected tab, but I'm not sure how as bootstrap uses Jquery which I don't know. My JS also doesn't work.

```js
let mathsTab = document.getElementById('Mathematics-tab');
if (mathsTab.getAttribute('aria-selected') == "true") {
    console.log("true");
   // mathsTab.style.color = #f0a500;
} else {
   // mathsTab.style.color = #1A1C20;
};
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill justify-content-center mt-3" id="myTab" role="tablist">
     <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
       <a class="nav-link active gold-text" id="Mathematics-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Mathematics" role="tab" aria-controls="Mathematics" aria-selected="true">Mathematics</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
       <a class="nav-link gold-text" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">English</a>
    </li>
     <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
       <a class="nav-link gold-text" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Verbal</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
       <a class="nav-link gold-text" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Nonverbal</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `mathsTab.style.color = #f0a500;` not valid, color is not in quotes

Comment: I added quotes now and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: What errors are thrown?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

Comment: What does *href color* even mean? Href is an attribute.

Comment: You can use CSS?

Comment: Both solutions work below thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean like that ?

```js
let navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
  navItems.forEach(item =>{
    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
      item.style.color = "#f0a500";
      navItems.forEach(otherItem => {
        if(otherItem !== item){
          otherItem.style.color = "#1A1C20";
        }
      });
    })
  })
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill justify-content-center mt-3" id="myTab" role="tablist">
 <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
   <a class="nav-link active gold-text" id="Mathematics-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Mathematics" role="tab" aria-controls="Mathematics" aria-selected="true">Mathematics</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
   <a class="nav-link gold-text" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">English</a>
</li>
 <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
   <a class="nav-link gold-text" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Verbal</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
   <a class="nav-link gold-text" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Nonverbal</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to distinguish between a selected and unselected tab

Bootstrap uses the `.active` class to denote which element is active. Based on your existing classes just add the following CSS:

```
#myTab .gold-text.active {
  color : gold;
}
```

Demo:

```css
#myTab .gold-text.active {
  color : gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill justify-content-center mt-3" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link active gold-text" id="Mathematics-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Mathematics" role="tab" aria-controls="Mathematics" aria-selected="true">Mathematics</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link gold-text" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">English</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link gold-text" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Verbal</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link gold-text" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Nonverbal</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change a tab (Mathematic-tab)to a different href color (so I can't put .style.color = gold), when the value of 'aria-selected' from bootstrap becomes true.

You don't need to use JavaScript; instead you can do it using a CSS attribute selector `.nav-link[aria-selected="true"]` to set the color.

Like this:

```css
.nav-link[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill justify-content-center mt-3" id="myTab" role="tablist">
 <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
   <a class="nav-link active gold-text" id="Mathematics-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Mathematics" role="tab" aria-controls="Mathematics" aria-selected="true">Mathematics</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
   <a class="nav-link gold-text" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">English</a>
</li>
 <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
   <a class="nav-link gold-text" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Verbal</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
   <a class="nav-link gold-text" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Nonverbal</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to restrict it to just the Mathematics tab then you can use `#Mathematics-tab[aria-selected="true"]` to filter on the element's ID rather than the `nav-link` class.

Comment: thanks, so [] can only be used for classes after an id has been mentioned right. E.g. id[class]

Comment: @github292929 No, if you want you can use `[aria-selected="true"]` on its own. And its `[attribute-name="value"]` and is independent of any element's ID or class.